# Vertical slide with PHPOffice

Tags: presentation, phpoffice

I'm using [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice) to generate a presentation based on DB data. It's a great library. Does anyone know how to set a presentation to vertical? On the [features](http://phppresentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html) it says it does support it, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The original developers answered my question:

```
$oDocumentLayout = new DocumentLayout();
$oDocumentLayout->setDocumentLayout(DocumentLayout::LAYOUT_A4, false);

$oPresentation = new PhpPresentation();
$oPresentation->getLayout($oDocumentLayout);
```